# Sql query to return column name, data type, data length, if a column is null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT column_name,
   data_type
   date_length
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_schema = ’bookidz_ro_dev’
AND    table_name = ’rack_level’;
```

And I get this error: #1054 - Unknown column '’bookidz_ro_dev’' in 'where clause'
even though the db name is correct and so is the table name.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: bookidz_ro_dev does not appear to be enclosed in single quote(s) and is seen as a column name in your query,

Comment: You need to change the curly quotation mark you used in bookidz_ro_dev and rack_level (’curly’) into a straight quotation mark ('straight').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i tested your code is good, but those ’ quotations are not correct.

```
SELECT 
*
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'bookidz_ro_dev'
AND    TABLE_NAME = 'rack_level';
```

I used * because there is no Date_Length column in information_schema.columns

Answer (score 0):

Looks like You are using wrong quotations, try it with correct one:

```
SELECT column_name,
   data_type
   date_length
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_schema = 'bookidz_ro_dev'
AND    table_name = 'rack_level';
```